# Use of MIN and COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, oracle-sqldeveloper, top-n

Can you give me an example at use of the min and count at the same query? For example on this table I want to know the lower number of workers with an odd Code (1 with the code 5).

```
 Table Workers
      Code
       1
       2
       2
       2
       3
       3
       1
       5
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a subquery to find the minimum, then use that to query again for the count:

```
select code, count(*)       -- get the count for the code found in the subquery
from workers
where code = (
    select min(code)        -- return the minimum code found
    from workers
    where mod(code, 2) = 1) -- only odd codes
group by code;              -- group by the non-aggregated column(s0
```

### Edited:

From comments, it seem you want the odd code with the least workers:

```
select code, count(*)
from workers
where mod(code, 2) = 1
group by code
order by 2
limit 1;
```

You don't say which database you're using, so the syntax for "returning only the first row" may vary from "LIMIT 1", which is the mysql way of doing it.

Comment: This finds the minimum odd code, he wants the odd code with the minimum count.

Comment: This queries the WORKERS table twice, which could be quite expensive in real life.  @bonsvr 's solution with the WITH clause is more efficient.

Comment: Oh, and the revised version uses `LIMIT`, which is not Oracle syntax (although to be fair the OP didn't originally specify the database product).

Answer (score 1):

This is for **`ORACLE`** and solves your problem.

```
with newt as
  (  select code, count(*) cnt
     from workers
     where mod(code, 2) = 1
     group by code)
select * 
from newt
where cnt in (select min(cnt) 
              from newt)
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct syntax for Oracle and the most efficient query.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that uses window functions and keeps all tied results. If you don't want many results when there are ties (but only an arbitrary one), use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`:

```
SELECT code
FROM
  ( SELECT code 
         , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) AS rnk
    FROM workers
    WHERE MOD(code, 2) = 1
    GROUP BY code 
  ) tmp
WHERE rnk = 1 ;
```

Tested in (Oracle 11g2): **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71220/6)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select Code, count(*) MinCount
from Workers
where mod(code, 2) = 1
group by Code
order by MinCount
limit 1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/022ce/3)

Note that if there are multiple codes with the minimum count, this selects just one of them arbitrarily. If you want all of them, that complicates things and you'll need a join with a subquery. Here's that query:

```
SELECT w.Code, CodeCount
FROM (SELECT Code, count(*) CodeCount
      FROM Workers
      WHERE mod(code, 2) = 1
      GROUP BY Code) w
JOIN (SELECT Code, count(*) MinCount
      FROM Workers
      WHERE mod(code, 2) = 1
      GROUP BY Code
      ORDER BY MinCount
      LIMIT 1) MinQuery
ON CodeCount = MinCount
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62e88/2)

Comment: I have one problem my database seems that doesn't accept a SELECT inside a FROM

Comment: What database are you using? You should tag the question with it.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer. Sorry.

Comment: I don't use Oracle, but from googling the `ORA-00933` error code it looks like it doesn't like `ORDER BY` in the subquery. I'm trying to modify it, but can't get even a simple query to work at sqlfiddle when I select Oracle. Maybe some Oracle wiz can figure out the revision.